# WebApplicationFactory gets connection string from service appsettings.json not test project appsettings.json

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, appsettings

My **api project** has an appsettings.json with a connection string for **"Settings"** database

My WebApplicationFactory in the **test project** has an appsettings.json with a connection string for **"Settings-IntegrationTests"** database

When I start a test from my **test project** using the WebApplicationFactory class:

```
internal sealed class TestWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<SettingsContext>>();              

                services.AddDbContext<SettingsContext>((container, options) =>
                {
                                        
                   options.UseNpgsql(ConfigurationReader.GetConnectionString());

                });
            });             
        }
    }
```

The api where I use the SettingDbContext does not have a connection string configured with "Settings-IntegrationTests" database instead "Settings" database.

**Program.cs**

```
  var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SettingsModel");
                builder.Services
                    .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                    .AddDbContext<SettingsContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
```

**ConfigurationReader.cs**

```
internal static class ConfigurationReader
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
            return configuration.GetConnectionString("SettingsModel");
        }

        public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            return configuration;
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with my setup in the TestWebApplicationFactory ?

Comment: but that shouldn't be a problem! both appsettings.json have same name in both projects.

Comment: [Could you kindly check this sample code ?](https://codeshare.io/VZ1Vw3)

Comment: @JasonPan that worked indeed! But now I have the problem of redundant + confusing code. I talk about my own ConfigurationReader class and the GetConfiguration method doing something redundant. How can I access the IConfigurationRoot in my ConfigureServices method ? Injecting it there with GetService<IConfigurationRoot> did not work!

Comment: If you have other issues, it's better to create a new thread with your concern, then other community users will help you.